# JavaFX tableView not populating with data from ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx

I am having difficulty populating a table view in JavaFX with data obtained in an ObservableList.

When btnConfirm() is pressed in PatientInfoController it creates a Patient object using on screen text data from the PatientInfoController view.

The object is then added to a LinkedList queue in the Queue class.
The queue is then returned and passed to the QueueTabPageController method displayQueue()

I know that the patient objects obtain the the required information when I print the enhanced for loop to console...

```
for (Patient patient : queue) {
        System.out.println(patient.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(patient.getLastName());
        System.out.println(patient.getPostCode());
        System.out.println(patient.getTriage());
        tableData.add(patient);
        System.out.println(tableData);
    }
```

But the tableView does not display the data in the cells.

(I have managed to get another tableview populating with search results from a database, but I am stumped on this one)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import app.Patient;
import app.Queue;
import app.Status;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PatientInfoController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Patient> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Patient, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Patient, String> lastNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label nhsNumberLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label titleLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lastNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label streetNumberLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label streetNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label cityLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label postCodeLabel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        assert personTable != null : "fx:id=\"tableView\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'PatientInfoPage.fxml'";
    }

    /**
     * Button to send user back to receptionist homepage
     * 
     * @param event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @FXML
    private void btnCancel(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    public static List<Patient> queue;

    public static QueueTabPageController queueTabPageController;

    /**
     * Button to confirm patient and send them to triage/waiting queue
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    @FXML
    private void btnConfirm(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow();
        // patientservicesclass psc = new patientservicesclass

        // test.enqueue("test");
        // psc.getPatientById(nhsNumberLabel.getText())
        Patient p = new Patient(firstNameLabel.getText(), lastNameLabel.getText(), nhsNumberLabel.getText(),
                titleLabel.getText(), streetNumberLabel.getText(), streetNameLabel.getText(), cityLabel.getText(),
                postCodeLabel.getText(), Status.EMERGENCY);

        queueTabPageController = new QueueTabPageController();

        queue = Queue.addToQueue(p);

        queueTabPageController.displayQueue(queue);

        stage.close();
    }

    /**
     * sets relevant labels to patient information from the database these
     * labels are set before screen is changed --- see btnPatientInfo on the
     * ReceptionistHomePageController for more info ---
     * 
     * @param patient
     */
    public void setPatientInfo(Patient patient) {
        nhsNumberLabel.setText(patient.getNhsNumber());
        titleLabel.setText(patient.getTitle());
        firstNameLabel.setText(patient.getFirstName());
        lastNameLabel.setText(patient.getLastName());
        streetNumberLabel.setText(patient.getStreetNumber());
        streetNameLabel.setText(patient.getStreetName());
        cityLabel.setText(patient.getCity());
        postCodeLabel.setText(patient.getPostCode());

    }

}
```

.

```
package app;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Queue implements Comparable<Patient> {

    /**
     * linked list of patient objects to represent queue
     */
    public static List<Patient> queue = new LinkedList<Patient>();

    /**
     * method to add a patient to the queue
     * 
     * @param p
     */
    public static List<Patient> addToQueue(Patient p) {

        // check to see if queue is full
        if (queue.size() < 10) {
            // add patient if there is room in queue
            queue.add(p);
        } else {
            // queue may be full
            System.out.println("Queue is full");
            // alert on call team and hospital manager
        }

        return queue;
        //test.displayQueue(queue);
    }

    /**
     * method to remove a patient from the queue
     * 
     * @param p
     */
    public static void removefromQueue(Patient p) {

        // remove patient from queue
        queue.remove(p);
    }

    /**
     * overriden method to allow comparison by triage status
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Patient o) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

.

```
package controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import app.Patient;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class QueueTabPageController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Patient> tableView = new TableView<Patient>();

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Patient, String> firstNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Patient, String> lastNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Patient, String> postCodeColumn;

    private ObservableList<Patient> tableData;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        assert tableView != null : "fx:id=\"tableView\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLQueueTabPage.fxml'";

        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("firstName"));
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("lastName"));
        postCodeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("postCode"));

    }


    public void displayQueue(List<Patient> queue) {

        tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        System.out.println("Starting display queue method in qtc + value of firstNameColumn = " + firstNameColumn);

        for (Patient patient : queue) {
            System.out.println(patient.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(patient.getLastName());
            System.out.println(patient.getPostCode());
            System.out.println(patient.getTriage());
            // tableData.addAll(queue);
            tableData.add(patient);
            System.out.println(tableData);
        }

        tableView.setItems(tableData);
        refreshTable();

    }

    void refreshTable() {
        final List<Patient> items = tableView.getItems();
        if( items == null || items.size() == 0) return;

        final Patient item = tableView.getItems().get(0);
        items.remove(0);
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                items.add(0, item);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

.

```
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="770.0" prefWidth="1000.0" stylesheets="@../styles/QueueTabPage.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.QueueTabPageController">
   <children>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#517da6" height="156.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" styleClass="rectangle-pane" width="1065.0" />
      <Label layoutX="349.0" layoutY="62.0" styleClass="label-queueTitle" stylesheets="@../styles/QueueTabPage.css" text="Accident &amp; Emergency Queue">
         <font>
            <Font size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="242.0" layoutY="276.0" prefHeight="384.0" prefWidth="718.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="122.0" text="First name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" prefWidth="144.0" text="Last name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="postCodeColumn" prefWidth="158.0" text="Time waiting" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Because you are dealing with `@fxml`, you don't have to use `private TableView<Patient> tableView = new TableView<Patient>();` in `public class QueueTabPageController`. That can just be `private TableView<Patient> tableView;` because that part gets handled in the `.fxml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly what happens is that the `TableView` gets populated and also painted, but because of this line: `private TableView<Patient> tableView = new TableView<Patient>();` another empty `TableView` gets painted over it. If you change

```
@FXML
private TableView<Patient> tableView = new TableView<Patient>();
```

to

```
@FXML
private TableView<Patient> tableView;
```

you should see the populated `tableView`.

Comment: I think you are doing the same thing there. You instantiate `queueTabPageController = new QueueTabPageController();` the controller. I'm not 100% sure but i think you don't have to do that.

Comment: When I change that line I now get the following NullPointerException error: `java.lang.NullPointerException at controllers.QueueTabPageController.displayQueue(QueueTabPageController.java:80) at controllers.PatientInfoController.btnConfirm(PatientInfoController.java:87) `     I have tried to debug but I am unsure of what exactly to do as I am new to Java and JavaFX.  Is there anything else that looks like it may not be right?

Comment: If you are not sure what to do, i would  recommend reading http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm to get some insight on what and what not to do. I think `queueTabPageController = new QueueTabPageController();` `queueTabPageController.displayQueue(queue);` could be handled differently. Because the controller is all about `fxml` and the display method doesn't involve `fxml` so you probably should move the `display` method to another or a new class.

Comment: The thing is that you use 2 controllers (it seems) , i don't have a lot experience with that. So far i have only written programs that use one. Using 2 would mean that there are more windows (stages) involved. But i will have to read into that soon. :)

Comment: OK, thank you for all the help anyway - I will read the documentation and look at the other points you've mentioned.  As I have 2 different pages, I have created 2 controllers.  I am not sure if this is correct practice or not.

Comment: If you have 2 different pages then you would need 2 controllers, but i have limited knowledge about how to let the 2 pages `talk` to eachother using the controllers. if thats needed or how to do that, like you did with `queueTabPageController = new QueueTabPageController();`, don't know if that is valid. But there should be enough info about it online.

Comment: But the problem is that you are creating a new controller instance: `queueTabPageController = new QueueTabPageController();` instead of using the already-existing instance.